# R- debug: line by line through a loop

Tags: rstudio

I try to find a way to debug through R studio, however all the solutions I can find do not really work.

1.) CTRL+enter: works but does not go through every iteration of the loop but only once.
2.) Adding "browser()" stops at that point but I am not able to go from there line by line (neither "n" nor "F10" works?

Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: I would like to debug a script. However I do not how I can activate the "comands" in the "Debut" tab?

Comment: The `browser()` method should work. Does the prompt change to `Browse[n]>` after execution stops? What happens when you type `n` at the prompt?

Comment: Many thanks! I reinstalled all, then it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Put the code/script inside a function:

```
function_to_debug <- function(data){ 
     a = 2+3 
     return(a)
}
```

Then run this in R console:

```
debug(function_to_debug)
```

The debugger starts and you can step through each line of the function.